# Two windows are presented when I start my xib only project

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

I am using Xcode 10.1 two create a simple single window application. The issue is that I see two windows instantiated when I run it instead of the single one I expect. Here is my code

//AppDelegate

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var mainWindowController: WindowController!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        print("loading")
        let mainWindowController = WindowController()
        mainWindowController.showWindow(self)
        self.mainWindowController = mainWindowController


    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
         print("closed")
    }


}
```

//WindowController.swift

```
import Cocoa

    class WindowController: NSWindowController, NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var speakButton: NSButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: NSButton!

        override var windowNibName: String {
          return "Window"
        }


        let speechSynth = NSSpeechSynthesizer()

        var isStarted: Bool = false {
            didSet {
               updateButtons()

            }
        }

        override func windowDidLoad() {
            super.windowDidLoad()
           viewDidLoad()
        }

         func viewDidLoad() {
           // super.viewDidLoad()
            updateButtons()
            speechSynth.delegate = self
            print("view load")


            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }



        @IBAction func speakIt(sender: NSButton) {
            let string = textField.stringValue
            if string.isEmpty {
                print("String is empty")
            }
            else {
                print(string)
                speechSynth.startSpeaking(string)
                isStarted = true
            }
        }

        @IBAction func stopIt(sender: NSButton) {
            speechSynth.stopSpeaking()
            isStarted = false
        }

        func updateButtons() {
            if isStarted {
                speakButton.isEnabled = false
                stopButton.isEnabled = true
            } else {
                stopButton.isEnabled = false
                speakButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        }

        func speechSynthesizer(_ sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer, didFinishSpeaking finishedSpeaking: Bool) {
            isStarted = false
        }
    }
```

My Xib has the option checked "Visible at launch". If I uncheck it, I see no window.

Basically, I am attempting a program from the book "Cocoa Programming for OSX". However, the book is obsolete. But I am trying to find my way through new Xcode and Swift. Any help?

Also a point worth noting is that only one window is functional, the second window IBOutlets and IBAction are not connected. So nothing happens in the second window.

I can't figure out why is this happening?

Comment: Precisely where in *Cocoa Programming for OSX* are you porting that code from?

Comment: BTW I suspect the code within `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is causing the duplicate window

Comment: The code is written in chapter 6, Delegation.

Comment: It's been a while but I don't believe any of the code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is required as creation of the window (and window controller) is all taken care of in the machinery of the XIB loading.

Comment: So here is the thing, If I comment the code in the method. The window loads only once , but it doesn't work. none of the button actions are working. My connections are contained in the file owner object, which is set to windowController. Can you tell me how this xib is loaded automatically? Can I disable this machinery?

Comment: The other problem with this autmatically loading xib is where do I put the code to initialize my xib? windowDidLoad() of WindowController is not called by this machinery.

Comment: self?.window?.rootViewController = mainWindowController

Comment: That book is one of the best on this subject; I learned a *ton* from reading it.  But you have to actually read it and understand it in order to progress.  I am not sure how much is still valid/possible but I recommend starting again with it and coding along in Objective-C and only once you understand it port the code to Swift.  Don't fight the NIB system - it is very powerful.

Comment: How can we reproduce the issue? Which files did you add and which changes did you make to the xibs? Did you try Clean in the Product menu?

Comment: You can reproduce it by creating a simple project with storyboard. Delete the storyboard and add a simple window.xib and the corresponding code files.

Comment: Did you change Main nib file base name in info.plist?

Comment: I removed that key altogether from info.plist

Comment: I tried your code and I get one window. Suggestion: Use the Xcode template without storyboard, this is probably the template used in the book.